# Efficient way to transform 3D matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an m x n x o matrix. I need to correct the position of elements in the matrix, because the data was sampled at an angle incident to the proper Cartesian axes. So for element ijk, I will have to shift the k position, based upon its position ij.

Is there an efficient vectorized way to do this, that isn't element by element?

Eg, for matrix element i,j,k;

kshift = calculate_kshift(i,j);

Data(i,j,k+kshift) = Data(i,j,k);

Thanks.

Comment: What does "_based upon its position ij_" mean? Post a small numerical example so that we see what you want

Comment: Don't shift the data. Shift the plot.

Comment: I'm not plotting the data. I just need the data to be represented in the proper Cartesian space.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm going to do is, for every line along the third dimension: Data(i,j,:), I'm going to shift the data by the calculated kshift.

Data(i,j,:) = Data(i,j,k-kshift)

Of course, with the appropriate bounds checks in place.

Comment: So this is not-an-answer to not-a-question?

Comment: If you have a better solution, I'd love to hear it.